# How ApacheBench can follow redirection

Tags: apache

I use AB(ApacheBench), Version 2.3.

I'm trying to test "http://localhost/myPage" with Basic Authentication.

There isn’t any problem when I use web browser like I.E.

The apache’s log message shows HTTP response code changing 401->301->200.

It saied my http request was finished successfully.

But when I use AB , result is different .

AB saied request was completed but Apache’s log shows status has stopped at 301.

Now,My question is how to get AB follows to redirect 301.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out "localhost/myPage" isn't correct path. I should have instead included a "/" at the end of URL like "localhost/myPage/".  Now AB follows redirect 301.

Comment: Are you sure? I cannot reproduce this. When I use `ab http://mysite/path`, I see one entry in logs with 307. If I do this with curl and -L and same URL: curl -L -I -x GET http://mysite/path, I see 2 entries, the 307 and the final page with 200 status code.

Comment: See also http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/200907.mbox/%3C980E202D-05FE-4868-8525-8BA63E235E6A@gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 3):

Based on my research AB doesn't follow redirects. I haven't checked the source code but I did a fair share of testing and googling around. My testing involved running AB tests and checking the access log. I was able to get redirects working with wget.

At one point I gave up on AB and installed **siege** instead, see http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/ for more details.

Comment: My article describs AB can follow 401->301->200.Then I tried how AB can follow 401->302->201.And AB couldn't follow it as you saeid.Do you tink I mustn't describe `redirect` for 401->301->201?

Comment: Well, the redirects are only 301 and 302 and not 401. And you expect the redirect to end with a 200 (not 201). I checked AB source code and it doesn't follow redirect (but I'm not sure I checked the latest source code).

Comment: Then, in my case it can be said AB can follow 301 to 200 but can't follow 302 isn't it?  Bytheway my apache is  Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) from http://www.apachelounge.com/download/