# different ApacheBench test results with URL ending with '/' or not

Tags: php, laravel, apachebench, lumen

I'd like to check the performance of a php framework, Lumen. So I use ab to have this test. But two very different results came from the following two commads:

```
ab -n 100 -c 20 http://local.lumen.com/login/
```

and

```
ab -n 100 -c 20 http://local.lumen.com/login
```

the first one is way much faster than the second one. QPS is like 7000+ vs 40+.
My question is why, and which one should I trust.

If I visit these two URLs on browser, both of them leads to the same page, which is `http://local.lumen.com/login`. This page doesn't have much things except a captcha. I tried this test on another framework Laravel. The difference is still there.

P.S. Environment: win7 x86_64, wampserver 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how `ab` command exactly works but I am sure that server (apache) kicks in and does 301 redirect therefore PHP itself is not hit at all.

```
ab -n 100 -c 20 http://local.lumen.com/login/
```

`example.com/login/` --- [301] --- to `example.com/login`

`ab` measures the redirect itself

when you do

```
ab -n 100 -c 20 http://local.lumen.com/login
```

`ab` measures the PHP execution time

---

It is all because Apache Benchmark does not follow redirects from discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22164728/1564365

Here is more information about ab I found kind of usefull https://www.rsreese.com/benchmarking-websites-with-ab-and-tsung/

Comment: Thanks, I checked the access log. It is 301 redirection when visiting `http://local.lumen.com/login/`

Comment: In addition when you check in browser, since 301 is "immediate" / "fast" you do not feel the speed that much. + your URL changes from `login/` to `login`